Archiving .NET MAUI apps on Mac VS/VS CODE
I need to archive a .NET MAUI iOS app on a Mac. There used to be an archive option in VS for Mac that would create an xcarchive. You could then go into XCode and publish it. There no longer seems to be this option in the now, end of life Visual Studio for Mac or VS Code.
I need to be able to create an xcarchive per Apple's instruction. A IPA file will not work. Does anyone know how to do this now?

You can use CLI to pubulish the app, for more details can refer to the official doc: Publish an iOS app using the command line.
Then open Xcode to find the xcarchive : Xcode->Window->Organizer->select the app->Archives

After following that, the publish command still produces a .ipa file. I need the .xcarchive like we used to get with Xamarin. I set ArchiveOnBuild to false as suggested in the article.

 A boolean value that indicates whether to produce the app archive. Use true to produce the .ipa.

Refer to this case: How do I use fastlane to compile my iOS app into an .xcarchive, then separately sign and make an IPA?.
